# How to print the word from a file in python

Tags: python, file

i tried using the .strip() method which give me the line

```
f = open("myFile.txt")#this open myfile
for i in range(500): # print 500 character 
    line = f.readline().strip() 
    print(line)
```

my expected result is

```
"faowijfaoijfaoiwjfioawjfafawjfaoiwjfawofjafw"
```

Comment: `f.read(100)` ...

Comment: this give me how many word instead of characted , eg number1 number number3   it will return me 3 , instead of counting character by character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.

```
with open("myFile.txt") as f:
    chars_100 = f.read(100)
    print (chars_100)
```